# Explicitly assign timezone to a timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone

Hitting my head on a wall with this one.  How do I tell Postgres the timezone of the unaware timestamp column?  I know the timezone based on another column in the database -- the timestamp value itself is unaware.

```
select 
  '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamp as without_tz, 
  '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/New_York' as with_tz
-------------------------
without_tz: 2017-07-10 01:30:00
with_tz:    2017-07-09 22:30:00-07
```

My desired output is:

```
with_tz:     2017-07-10 01:30:00-07
```

Comment: Check http://phili.pe/posts/timestamps-and-time-zones-in-postgresql/. You probably need to `SET timezone` before your select...

Comment: Hi thanks!  `SET timezone to 'America/New_York'` does work; however, it doesn't seem to accept a variable as the timezone ... and I need that! Grr.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
SELECT '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';
>> 2017-07-10 01:30:00
```

First, the output indicates your time zone is set to America/Los_Angeles or some other time zone definition that results in times being UTC-7. You may confirm this with `SHOW TIME ZONE;`.

Second, `AT TIME ZONE` functions differently on a timestamp or timestamptz. See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT), but a timestamp is **treated** as the specified time zone and **returned** as local time with time zone:

**Treat timestamp as New York, return as local timestamptz:**

```
SELECT '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';
>> 2017-07-09 22:30:00-07
```

While a timestamptz is **treated** as local time, **converted** to the specified time zone and returned as timestamp without time zone.

**Convert local timestamptz to New York timestamp**

```
SELECT '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York';
>> 2017-07-10 04:30:00
```

Once you understand the timestamp-timestamptz conversion happening, you can reliably chain the `AT TIME ZONE` command.

**Convert local timestamptz to New York timestamp which is treated as Chicago time and returned as local timestamptz:**

```
SELECT '2017-07-10 01:30:00'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';
>>  2017-07-10 02:30:00-07
```

To explain this more explicitly, this query converts a local timestamptz 1:30a to New York timestamp 4:30a, then treats 4:30a as Chicago timestamp and returns a local timestamptz 2:30a.

Similarly, the short answer above treats 1:30a as New York timestamp, then converts it to New York timestamptz 1:30a.